# How to remove previously updated UIElement on grid row to add new UIElement?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, row

I am working in silverlight where i have a grid called "bigGrid" which contains three rows and on the first row  i have combobox and i update two UI elemnt on two different rows on Loading the comboBox (i mean second row bigGrid(because bigGrid is parent of all) or first and second row of rowGrid in my code).

Now on selectionChanged Event of combobox i have to replace the previously rendered UI elemnts with the UI element selected from combo box (If the UIelement is one it will be displayed on one row and if the UI elements are two they will be displayed on two different rows one after other (Please note that on Loading this combobox i display 2 UI elemnts in 2 consecutive rows.)

**Now  Problem ?:** The problem in when i load combobox the grids are intialised with two UIelement on 2 rows. but on Selectionchnaged event when i render 2 uielements then it wroks fine for 2 UIElements (it replaces the previous rendering of Loaded event on both rows . **But the problem is when i dispaly only 1 UIElement in first row**  because MY RECENTLY RENDERED uiElement on selection changed event is no doubt updated in first row but the UI element of second row (from combobox Loaded even still persists).

**How to delete this PREVIOUSLY persisting UI element ?**

My code for (please note that i have given just useful code. Ofcourse combe is declared somewhere and it has Items as well)

```
public Grid somefunction() //this function returs the final bigGrid (which contains all the ROWS CONATINING ui ELEMNTS)
    {
      cmb.Loaded += (o3, e) =>
                {
                    foreach (object o in pv.Root.Parameter)
                    {
                        param = (Parameter)o;
                        if (o is Parameter)
                        {
                         rowGrid = IntializeUIElements(param, atrbt);
                        } 
                        Grid.SetRow(rowGrid, loopCount);
                    }
                        bigGrid.Children.Add(rowGrid);
                        loopCount++;
                };




     cmb.SelectionChanged += (o1, e) =>
                {
                    string selectedComboItem = cmb.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    Grid storeRowGrid = new Grid();
                    for (int i = 0; i < pv.Root.Parameter.Count; i++)
                    {
                        storeRowGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto });
                    }
                    int count = 0;
                    foreach (object o in pv.Root.Parameter)
                    {
                        if (o is Parameter)
                        {
                            rowGrid = IntializeUIElements(param, atrbt); //It returns the grid with UI element
                            Grid.SetRow(rowGrid, count);
                            storeRowGrid.Children.Add(rowGrid);
                            Grid.SetRow(storeRowGrid, count);
                            if (bigGrid.Children.Count > 1)
                            {
                                bigGrid.Children.RemoveAt(bigGrid.Children.Count - 1); //this is to remocve previous item on selection change
                            }
                            count++;
                        }

                    }             

                             bigGrid.Children.Add(storeRowGrid);
                };

                Grid.SetColumn(cmb, 1);
                comboRowGrid.Children.Add(cmb);
                Grid.SetRow(comboRowGrid, 0);
                bigGrid.Children.Add(comboRowGrid); //This BigGrid is parent Grid.
                return bigGrid;
    }
```

**How to clear the previous UI element of Loaded event on second row when selection changed event show just 
& uielement in first row ?**

Comment: Instead of adding X elements into X rows, and having to track how many were added and then removing them, you could just add X elements into a grid with X rows ... and then place that grid into a single row. When you want to replace that control you then just replace a single grid in a single row, and don't have to care about how controls/rows were within that grid.

Comment: @Mashton sorry i couldnt understand you.Could you please explain a more in detail? Actually my first row of bigGrid will always conatina comboBox and on the basis of value selected in combo box the Uielements will be displayed in the rows below the combobox.The problem is when the UI elements are 2 at load time and on selectionchanged event if UI elment is 1 then the first one will be replaced but the second row UI element has nothing to replace so it still appears.(as result first UI elemnent in first row from selectionc changed event and second row UI elemet from loaded) Thanks the problem

Comment: See my answer, so that I could get some proper code layout displayed

Answer (score 1):

Your layout is something like this:

```
<Grid>
  <ComboBox Grid.Row="0"/>
  <SomeControl Grid.Row="1"/>
  <SomeOtherControl Grid.Row="2"/>
   ...
</Grid>
```

If you made it more like this:

```
<Grid>
  <ComboBox Grid.Row="0"/>
  <Grid x:Name="grid with controls chosen by the Combobox selection" Grid.Row="1">
    <SomeControl Grid.Row="0"/>
    <SomeOtherControl Grid.Row="1"/>
  </Grid>
   ...
</Grid>
```

You wouldn't have to worry about how many controls to remove, because you can just remove/replace a single grid.

Comment: i do this way because i  reuse the code for generatingGrid in function in IntializeUIElements() .

Comment: And one more thing you know on selection change of combobox i display the UI elements on same grids (the UI elements just replaces each other, so i reuse the grids as well)

Comment: In the first example I showed there were 3 children in the grid. In the second there were 2, and that second child itself had 2 children. What do you mean more than 1 child of layoutroot?

Comment: your logic is i guess not correct. FOR THE FIRST TIME when we do not do selection change it will display two UI elments below the grid. but when you do selectionc changed then it will not dispaly combobox next time (because we already removed those grids Inside the selection changed event in order to have new Ui elemnts). so on selection change element we will not have combo box second time on selctionchanged .Am i right ?

Comment: I know no idea what you are saying. First time, when no selection changed, I have no idea what you are doing - are you displaying two UI elements? My answer says nothing about handling selection changed, or loading the form. My answer is not telling you how to write your code, I am just giving you a different approach. You said you didn't know how to remove two elements and replace them with one element. I said, you don't need to: you just replace one element (grid with X elements) with one element (grid with Y elements).